# Bitbucket Pipeline composer not found despite I install is as composer doc's say

Tags: php, composer-php, bitbucket-pipelines

In my project I try to package my app:

```
image: php:8.1

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - composer
        script:
          - php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
          - php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
          - php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
          - chmod +x /usr/local/bin/composer
    - step:
        caches:
          - composer
        script:
          - export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
          - composer install
          - ./vendor/bin/phpunit
    
    - step:
        caches:
          - composer
        script:
          - export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
          - composer install --no-dev
          - apt-get update && apt-get install -y zip
          - export FILE=release-$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S").zip 
          - zip ${FILE} ./lib/*.php ./vendor/* composer.json composer.lock index.php config.php ./utils/*.php
          - curl -X POST --user "${BB_AUTH_STRING}" "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/${BITBUCKET_REPO_OWNER}/${BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG}/downloads" --form files=@"${FILE}"
        artifacts:
          - release-$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S").zip
```

But at step:

```
   - step:
        caches:
          - composer
        script:
          - export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
          - composer install
          - ./vendor/bin/phpunit
```

I get the error:

```
bash: composer: command not found
```

Do you know why? Is seems like for some reason between each steps the installed composer is not shared.

Comment: `caches: composer` doesn't mean composer itself is shared, it means composer's cache is shared. Each step is run in a different container, so if you're going to use composer in each, then you have to install composer in each. (Or use an image that already has composer in it.) Your first step does nothing -- it just starts a container, installs composer, and then throws the container away.

Comment: So I need to do composer install and then export the installed dependencies as artifacts or build my own image outside the bithucket actions and use that.

Comment: If you want to run phpunit in a step then you will need to install and run composer in that step. If you want to zip the vendor subdir in a step, then you will need to install and run composer in that step. You could also build your own custom image with composer and zip already installed. Artifacts are only needed for files you want to keep around after the step finishes, like your zip file.

Comment: You could make it into a custom cache, with some script checking to see if you got it and install it if not, but to save build time the Docker with the dependency would be the easiest and fastest as Alex said.
 https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/cache-dependencies/#Custom-caches-for-other-build-tools-and-directories

Answer (score 1):

`caches: composer` doesn't mean composer itself is shared, it means composer's cache is shared. Each step is run in its own standalone container, so if you're going to use composer in each, then you have to install composer in each. In your example, your first step does nothing -- it just starts a container, installs composer, and then throws the container away. You could have two steps, one to test and one to build the zip, each installing and running composer:

```yaml
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - composer
        script:
          - php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
          - php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
          - php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
          - chmod +x /usr/local/bin/composer
          - export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
          - composer install
          - ./vendor/bin/phpunit
    - step:
        caches:
          - composer
        script:
          - php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
          - php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
          - php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
          - chmod +x /usr/local/bin/composer
          - export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
          - composer install --no-dev
          - apt-get update
          - apt-get install -y zip
          - export FILE=release-$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S").zip 
          - zip ${FILE} ...
          - curl ...
        artifacts:
          - release-$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S").zip
```

Alternatively, you could build your own custom image based on `php:8.1`, with composer and zip already installed -- and then reference that in your pipe config.

```yaml
image: my_custom_image_with_composer_and_zip_already_in_it:8.1

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - composer
        script:
          - composer install
          - ./vendor/bin/phpunit
    - step:
        caches:
          - composer
        script:
          - composer install --no-dev
          - export FILE=release-$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S").zip 
          - zip ${FILE} ...
          - curl ...
        artifacts:
          - release-$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S").zip
```

Comment: Could I use the installed composer as an artifact? and pass it around upon each step?
Also does bithucket have its own docker repository as well for internal use in pipelines?

Comment: I suppose? But you'd have to install it in the project dir, not in /usr/local/bin. And you'd have to make sure all steps use the same image (or at least the same OS version.) And you wouldn't be able to use parallel steps at all.

Comment: @DimitriosDesyllas picking files that ought to be managed by a package manager is generally a bad idea. You should better cache downloads and intermediate built files and issue a regular install irrespective of the presence of any cache.